# Removing default padding on Vuetify v-app-bar

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, appbar

Vuetify `v-app-bar` has default css classeses `v-toolbar__content` and `v-toolbar__extension` that adds `16px` padding on x-axis and `4px` on y-axis that I want to get rid of.

I have tried overriding these classes in my css like below

```
.v-toolbar__content {
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Anybody aware of some trick that would help get rid of the padding in `v-app-bar`?

Comment: do you have app.scss file ?

Comment: No, I am overriding it in scoped style

Comment: I cant do that also inside my scope style, I just putted in on my general style.

Comment: @Qonvex620 I tried adding to global CSS but it doesnt work. I think that is what you meant.

Comment: Do other style descriptions described in the same place work?

Comment: @Lana like what?

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary Does only rule for `.v-toolbar__content ` not work but other styles works? Can you add arbitrary styles and check if styles work at all or not? because you wrote that adding in global CSS doesn't help. Maybe the problem is in project building and your styles are not loaded at all.

Answer (score 10):

In scoped styles, you cannot access child components directly. You need to use **deep selector** like this.

```
/deep/ .v-toolbar__content {
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Or if you want to target using child selector, you can do:

```
.parent-class >>> .v-toolbar__content {
      padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: The first suggestion worked for me, with the deep selector, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend modifying the vuetify SCSS variables.
According to the [v-toolbar API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-toolbar/#sass-variables) we can modify $toolbar-content-padding-y and $toolbar-content-padding-x in our variables style file.

```
$toolbar-content-padding-x: 0;
$toolbar-content-padding-y: 0;
```

If you haven't configured a variable file, please follow the [SASS variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/) guide.